# TypeError when trying to deploy a contract with web3 1.0.0-beta.11

Tags: solidity, web3js, solc

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy a contract with web3 in version 1.0.0-beta.11,  and I don't know if I'm hitting a bug in web3, an incompatibility issue with the version of solc I'm using, or if I'm just doing something wrong.

I'm using the latest version of solc released on NPM: 0.4.13. I'm trying to deploy the following contract:

```
contract Greetings {
    string message;

    function Greetings() {
        message = "I am ready!";
    }

    function setGreetings(string _message) public {
        message = _message;
    }

    function getGreetings() constant returns (string) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

with the following series of instructions run in a node console:

```
sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('Greetings.sol').toString()
compiledCode = solc.compile(sourceCode)
contractABI = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Greetings'].interface)

[ { constant: false,
inputs: [ [Object] ],
name: ‘setGreetings’,
outputs: [],
payable: false,
type: ‘function’,
signature: ‘0x49da5de4’ },
{ constant: true,
inputs: [],
name: ‘getGreetings’,
outputs: [ [Object] ],
payable: false,
type: ‘function’,
signature: ‘0xca4c3a41’ },
{ inputs: [],
payable: false,
type: ‘constructor’,
signature: ‘constructor’ } ]

contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI)
byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':Greetings'].bytecode
contract.deploy({data: byteCode, arguments:[]}).send({from: '0x00D1AE0A6fC13B9ecdefA118B94cF95ac16D4ab0', gas: 4700000}).on('error', function(error){console.error(error);}).then(function(newContractInstance){console.log(newContractInstance.options.address)})
```

and there on the last one, I'm getting the following cryptic error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /Users/jdoe/myproject/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js:356:43
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is value of `contractABI` as of the fourth line?

Comment: Updated the question to show the contract ABI

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace than that, or just that one line?

Comment: I have an error while i am trying to deploy smart contract in my private blockchain using node server showing error cannot read property 'address' of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're being bitten by [#948](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/948).  Also see [this other question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/how-to-get-value-of-a-contract-public-property-using-web3-eth/23062#23062).  Should be resolved in `-beta.12`, apparently